# FormulaR1C1 in cycle

Tags: vba

I have code like this for cycle that should be repeated lets say 10 times.

```
Sub formula()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 10
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=INDEX('C100 Month End AR251'!R1C1:R8434C28,MATCH('Reclassed items'!R2C11,'C100 Month End AR251'!C11,0),i)"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Next i
End Sub
```

As you can see, last variable is i, but excel takes it as text and number from cycle is not calculated so I am getting error #NAME? in excel sheet, and in formula is letter i insted of number of column 1 - 10.

Thank you for help

Comment: the `i` needs to be outside the quotes and concatenated.  `...0)," & i & ")"`

Comment: Also, instead of using `ActiveCell.Offset(0,1).Select` you could use the `Cells()` function to move through the 10 columns.  I don't know what row you are on, but you can use something like this `Cells(1,i).FormulaR1C1 = ......`

Comment: No loop needed: `ActiveCell.Resize(1, 10).FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX('C100 Month End AR251'!R1C1:R8434C28,MATCH('Reclassed items'!R2C11,'C100 Month End AR251'!C11,0),Columns(" & ActiveCell.Address(1, 1, xlR1C1) & ":RC))"`